# Why would retransformClasses fail silently?

Tags: java, jvm, instrumentation, javaagents

I'm trying to retransform classes with java instrumentation. The code below runs just fine, it prints `Hello World!!`.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        var inst = MyAgent.getInstrumentation();
        inst.addTransformer(new ClassFileTransformer() {
            @Override
            public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String name, Class<?> c, ProtectionDomain pd, byte[] b) {
                if (c != Main.class) return null;
                var cr = new ClassReader(b);
                var cw = new ClassWriter(cr, ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
                cr.accept(new ClassVisitor(ASM9, cw) {
                    @Override
                    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int acc, String name, String desc, String sig, String[] exc) {
                        var mv = super.visitMethod(acc, name, desc, sig, exc);
                        if ("foo".equals(name)) {
                            return new MethodVisitor(ASM9, mv) {
                                @Override
                                public void visitCode() {
                                    super.visitCode();
                                    visitFieldInsn(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
                                    visitLdcInsn("Hello ");
                                    visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "print", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
                                }
                            };
                        }
                        return mv;
                    }
                }, 0);
                return cw.toByteArray();
            }
        }, true);
        inst.retransformClasses(Main.class);
        foo();
    }

    public static void foo() {
        System.out.println("World!!");
    }
}
```

However, when the `ClassFileTranformer` returns invalid bytecode, or when it just returns `new byte[0]`, the retransformation fails silently. No exceptions are thrown and no changes are done. According to the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#retransformClasses(java.lang.Class...)), if invalid bytes are provided, the method should throw a exception. The doc says:

> The class file bytes are not checked, verified and installed until after the transformations have been applied, if the resultant bytes are in error this method will throw an exception.

Using the instrumentation object outside the java agent doesn't seem to be a problem, I tried to put the retransformation code in the agent and the behaviours are exactly the same. I'm using GraalVM EE (the version is shown below). I tried OpenJDK as well and it still fails silently.

```
java version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment GraalVM EE 22.3.1 (build 17.0.6+9-LTS-jvmci-22.3-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM EE 22.3.1 (build 17.0.6+9-LTS-jvmci-22.3-b11, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Why it fails silently? Is it because I'm using instrumentation in a wrong way? How can I get a exception when the bytecode is malformed? Thanks in advance.

(Thanks to Johannes Kuhn, corrected the unsupported use of ASM Api)

Comment: If your transformer throws, the instrumentation API will silently discard the exception.

Comment: Also, you use the ASM Api in an unsupported way: `visitCode` has to be called before `visitFieldInsn`. You call it after, which may or may not result in problems. And... depending on other factors, there might not be enough stack space in the target method - so pass `ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAX` to the `ClassWriter` constructor.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Thanks for pointing out the problem with the ASM Api usage. I had a look at the source code and indeed, the internal implementation catches the exception thrown by the transformer and ignores it, but in my case the transformer won't throw. The doc says `retransformClasses` will throw a exception if the transformer returns malformed bytecode, but when my transformer just returns something like `new byte[0]`, nothing happens. Why?